# How can configure two tables for admin module?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, admin, adminhtml

I have a custom module. I am using this module to upload images through admin. I have 6 more form fields in my module. I am currently using one table to store values of these form fields. However as like in magento, i am planning to store image values in another table. My table structure is given below.

```
Table : Banner

    Fields :  banner_id( primary_key , int(11) ) 

              banner_name( varchar (250) )

              banner_count( small_int (6) )

              status( small_int (6) )  

              store_id( varchar (250) )   

Table : banner_images

    Fields : bi_id( primary_key , int (11) ) 

             banner_id( int (11) ) //this should be the 'banner_id' of banner which holds this imge

             bi_name( varchar (255) ) //stores image_name
```

My current edit file look like this:

```
<?php
    class Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->_objectId = 'id';
            $this->_blockGroup = 'banner';
            $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_banner';
            $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('banner')->__('Save Banner'));
            $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('banner')->__('Delete Banner'));

        }

        public function getHeaderText()
        {
            if( Mage::registry('banner_data') && Mage::registry('banner_data')->getId() ) 
            {
                return Mage::helper('banner')->__("Edit Banner");
            } 
            else 
            {
                return Mage::helper('banner')->__('Add Banner');
            }
        }
    }
```

My sql file look like this :

```
?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->run("
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('banner')};
            CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('banner')} (
                `banner_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                `banner_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                `banner_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
                `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
                `store_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
       ");
   $installer->endSetup();
```

How can I achieve this? Please provide links, if there is any tutorials for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use [This Link](http://zaheerbadi.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/multiple-db-tables-in-single-custom-module-in-magento/ ) to create multiple table in your custom module

Comment: hello can i make chat with you. I have an issue for this module. i think you can help me.

Comment: Hello Rajeev how can i help you